# WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException - Selenium RemoteWebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, invocationtargetexception, remotewebdriver

I use Selenium to run a desktop app that has a Web view.  Two days ago, my process worked just fine and my tests were running, but I must have done something with my manual testing that changed files on my computer or something changed with files I need for Selenium, because now I can launch my app, see the Web View, but the app closes before my tests can interact with it.

I run a selenium standalone server and I see the following stack trace each time the process fails:

```
C:\Git\MyDesktopApp.AutomatedTests\bin\Debug>REM @Echo off

C:\Git\MyDesktopApp.AutomatedTests\bin\Debug>REM Use "REM" (wh
ich is a batch file comment) to Toggle between the commands below to change to a
 different location (version) of MyDesktopApp.

C:\Git\MyDesktopApp.AutomatedTests\bin\Debug>REM MAKE SURE THA
T YOU HAVE DOWNLOADED VERSION *2.47.1* OF THE SELENIUM SERVER STANDALONE JAR FIL
E AND PLACED IT IN THE FOLLOWING PATH: REPOSITORYFOLDER\MyDesktopAppAutomatedTests\bin\Debug

C:\Git\MyDesktopApp.AutomatedTests\bin\Debug>java.exe -jar .\s
elenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Program Files
 (x86)\MyDesktopApp-debug\MyDesktopApp.exe"
13:12:17.106 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to C:\Program Files (x86)\MyDesktopApp.exe
13:12:17.215 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.51-b03
13:12:17.215 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
13:12:17.221 INFO - v2.47.1, with Core v2.47.1. Built from revision 411b314
13:12:17.256 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
13:12:17.256 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not re
gistered
13:12:17.410 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.
1:4444/wd/hub
13:12:17.411 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
13:12:17.979 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=chrome,
javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]])
13:12:17.986 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{browserName=chrome
, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]
13:12:38.871 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'w7-alitwick', ip: '10.21.0.19', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arc
h: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSessi
on.java:183)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSessio
n.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(Defaul
tSession.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(De
faultDriverSessions.java:125)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSessio
n.java:58)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSessio
n.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConf
ig.java:111)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleReques
t(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:175)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverS
ervlet.java:202)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.
java:164)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet
.java:130)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.jav
a:428)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler
.java:680)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.j
ava:571)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)

        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:9
86)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.
java:243)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationT
argetException
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'w7-alitwick', ip: '10.21.0.19', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arc
h: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstruct
or(DefaultDriverProvider.java:113)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(D
efaultDriverProvider.java:97)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(De
faultDriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(
DefaultSession.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(
DefaultSession.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession
.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstruct
or(DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not sta
rt a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or br
owser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'w7-alitwick', ip: '10.21.0.19', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arc
h: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.ja
va:589)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriv
er.java:242)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.jav
a:128)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.jav
a:141)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)

        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:138)

        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The process has not exited yet there
fore no result is available ...
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecuteResultHandler.getException(Defa
ultExecuteResultHandler.java:76)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.checkForError(UnixProcess.java:171
)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.checkForError(CommandLine.java:183
)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.
java:169)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(Driv
erCommandExecutor.java:63)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.ja
va:568)
        ... 19 more
13:12:38.878 WARN - Exception: The process has not exited yet therefore no resul
t is available ...
```

I have tried:
- Updating my selenium files through NuGet
- Updating my ChromeDriver
- Verified that Chrome is working
- Updating my server .jar files
- reinstalled Java
- Verified that my RemoteWebDriver is pointed to http://127.0.0.1:4444
- Verified that my .bat file contains the correct version (2.47.1) of selenium standalone server

And still, this is not working.
My guess is that maybe my .jar file dependencies are messed up, but I don't know how to fix them if that is the case.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Why do you set YOUR app as the chrome-driver? Looking at the log and your description of whats happening, it seems like selenium tries to execute the "ChromeDriver" you provide (which is your app and the reason you see it opening), then tries to connect to it (which it should not be able to, because your app probably does not provide the ChromeDriver-API, which the ChromeDriver would) and then dies due to this, taking your app down with it in a proper teardown of the selenium-session...

Comment: I'm not the one who set it up this way. I was just hired to take over this automation project and the developers that had worked on it before had found a loop-hole in Selenium to allow it to run with the MVC app that has a web View.  Like I said, it was working before - the application was being interacted with. Then, the next time I opened it, it started breaking. Here is the Start method which defines the driver object.  I hope maybe that can give someone a clue as to how this might be fixed. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: public class AppDriver
    {
        public static AppDriver Instance = new AppDriver();

        public IWebDriver driver { get; private set; }

        
        public void Start()
        {

            if (driver != null)
                return;
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.Chrome(), new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));0));

        }

Comment: In speaking with one of our devs, our app does have the ChromeDriver API implemented into it.